# From a component in a v-for loop, get both loop index and an emitted value

Tags: vue.js

I have a component which is created by a v-for loop. The index of the for loop is important to me, and I also have to pass data with the emit method of the component to the parent. How can I get both these values, namely a value from the component child which is emitted, and also the index of the loop from the parent?

My template:

```
<div
v-for="(presc, index) in editedPrescription"
:key="index"
>
    <autocomplete-input 
    placeholder="Brand name"
    arialabel="BrandName"
    :searcheventresults="brandformattedsearchresults"
    :defaultterm="editedPrescription[index].brand"
    minimum-letters-to-trigger="4"
    @changed="BrandSearch"
    @selected="SelectedBrand(index)"
    />
</div>
```

In the child component, in a method:

```
Select(vindex) {
    console.log(`In Autocomplete widget, Selected vindex: ${vindex}`);
    this.searchterm = this.searcheventresults[index]
    this.$emit("selected", vindex);
},
```

When I try to get the emitted value in the parent method:

```
SelectedBrand(i, j) {
  console.log(`In SelectedBrand, i:`, i);
  console.log(`j:`, j);
},
```

In console,

```
In SelectedBrand, i: 0
PrescriptionBlock.vue ? c2fe : 1155 j: undefined
```

How can I get both these values? With my current implementation, I can get only the index of the loop. If I change to `@selected="SelectedBrand"`, then I can get the emitted value from child component. But I lose the index of the loop. I need both.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an anonymous function like this :

```
@selected="(arg) => {SelectedBrand(arg, index)}"
```

Comment: Can you kindly explain your answer. Please tell me how this works.

Comment: Handler events like @selected take a function as a parameter with possible arguments, if we call the SelectedBrand method directly we don't have access to the key of the parent div since only the emitted parameters will be transmitted. The principle is to use an anonymous function that allows us to have access to the local context (here the parent div with its key) and also to the emitted parameters and then call our method with these 2 arguments.